# Laravel combine multiple collections into one query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm wondering if this is possible. I have 3 models.
Users
TenantPreferances
PropertyAdverts

I'm trying to find out if I can do a query like so.

Find all tenants, whose preferences, match the currently signed in users properties.

The 3 databases are like so

User Model

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('userType');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

PropertyAdverts

```
Schema::create('property_adverts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string("photo");
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('county');
            $table->string('town');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->string('rent');
            $table->string('date');
            $table->string('bedrooms');
            $table->string('bathrooms');
            $table->string('furnished');
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->integer('user_id'); //Landlord ID
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Tenant Preferances

```
 Schema::create('tenant_preferances', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('county');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->string('rent');
        $table->string('bedrooms');
        $table->string('bathrooms');
        $table->boolean('status')->default('0');
        $table->integer('user_id'); //Tenant ID
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. You need to dig in on [relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships). You can then create a function to define the relation on you model:

```
function propertyAdverts() {
  return $this->hasMany(PropertyAdverts::class);
}
```

You can access the relation from the user model by using `$user->propertyAdverts`. If you want to eager load them you can do so:

```
User::with('propertyAdverts')->find(3);
```

But notice that Laravel does not do a regular join by default. It first fetches all users, and then fetches all `propertyAdverts` using a single query using a `in` statement.